# How can I get the intermediate layer output with dnnlib.tflib.network.Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, model, nvidia

I am trying StyleGAN2 NviLab，and I want to watch feature maps while generating, but how can I get the intermediate layer output? The model is loaded by dnnlib.tflib.network.Network and no document about this lib.

Comment: Try these answers, they seem to address your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57410282/tensorflow-2-hub-how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46560313/is-there-an-easy-way-to-get-something-like-keras-model-summary-in-tensorflow/52029732

Comment: I knew keras can get  intermediate layer output, but here I can't transfer my trained model to keras format. It used dnnlib.tflib, an additional lib in projects of Nvilab.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue, with the exact same codebase. This is how I got intermediate outputs (TF 1.14.0):

Step 1:

Check the names of all layers, and their output shapes. This helps identify the name of the layer whose output you want:

```
network.print_layers()
```

Step 2:

Get a list of all layers in the network. Each element in this list is a tuple `(layer name: string, layer output: tensor, layer variables)`

```
layers = network.list_layers()
```

Step 3:

Get a reference to the tensor representing the layer's output, using the name of the layer whose output you need:

```py
for layer in layers:
    print(layer[0], ' ', layer[1])
    if layer[0] == REQUIRED_LAYER_NAME:
        tensor = layer[1]
```

Finally, run the graph:

```py
required_output = sess.run(tensor, feed_dict={'INPUT_TENSOR_NAME': input_numpy_array})
```